# Drupal 6: Advertisement module for particular page with channel

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, ads, taxonomy

I use http://drupal.org/project/ad module. I have taxonomy pages for locations and I need to display location specific ads. so I have created a Channel for a location, and set the url (see below) and added my print ad() code to page. then, created some ads for the channel, but it doesnt display any ads under the provided url :/ any idea what am I doing wrong?

Appreciate helps!! thanks a lot!

---

**Channel Setting Page:**
[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100712-eb5jn53e4rbkxbiugi77iw9gfu.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100712-eb5jn53e4rbkxbiugi77iw9gfu.jpg)

---

**page-taxonomy-term.tpl.php**

```
<?php print ad(); ?>
```

Comment: is "london-pubs" an alias for an url like "taxonomy/term/123"?

Comment: yes it is , and I just tried with http://www.blabla.com/taxonomy/term/11 for URL Rules. but still no display any belonged ads. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the relative path. 'london-pubs' and/or 'london-pubs*' should work.

Comment: I can't believe myself! so silly! Thanks a lot for opening my eyes! Appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Look at the description under the input field, it says

> If serving ads locally use Drupal
>   relative oaths. If serving ads
>   remotely include the "http:" or
>   "https.//"